# Apple Swift - Unable to retrieve data from CMPedometer's handler

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I am trying out Swift with some of the new iOS 8 API's and have tried the best part of the day to get the CMPedometer queryPedometerDataFromDate API to return any data within the handler. I believe its an error on my part, getting a little confused with the syntax.

Here is my code, with comments on what prints out:

```
    var ped = CMPedometer()
    var stepsTaken = NSNumber(int: 0)

    println(dateNow) // 2014-06-07 21:23:55 +0000
    println(dateMidnight) // 2014-06-07 00:00:00 +0000

    ped.queryPedometerDataFromDate(dateMidnight, toDate: dateNow, withHandler:{
        data, error in
        println("Test1") // Does not print
        println(error) // Does not print
        stepsTaken = data.numberOfSteps
        })

    println("My Int Value \(stepsTaken)")  // My Int Value 0
```

Comment: In a playground? If you call `CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable()` it returns `false`, which might explain why you can't get a step count... I've not seen much on simulating hardware within a playground yet.

Comment: (And if you're *not* in a Playground, where are you running, and what does `CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable()` return for you?)

Comment: Hi there Matt. 
This is not in a playground, and CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable() returns true as I am running on an iPhone 5S. I have checked on my test device's privacy settings that it has access to motion data too.

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes things clearer. Sorry, there's so many people playing with Swift at the moment that there's a lot of rookie errors on SO, so it's easy to underestimate what people are trying! Unfortunately, I only have a 4S, so I don't think I've any way of testing it here.

Comment: I think the API call is broken, so I'll file a radar.
I've started to use CMStepCount (which is due to be depreciated? NS_CLASS_DEPRECATED_IOS(7_0,8_0,"Use CMPedometer instead")) and the same API call I'm trying above works perfectly in CMStepCount.

Comment: Do I have to import something to access this?

Answer (score 5):

It works for me with CMPedometer queryPedometerDataFromDate, if i define the CMPedometer as a class wide constant:

```
    let pedometer = CMPedometer()
```

and then in a func i'm using:

```
    self.pedometer.queryPedometerDataFromDate(today, toDate: now, withHandler: ...
```

Comment: Yup, the key is **not** to instantiate CMPedometer as a local variable, which is then out-of-scope by the time the results block is called.

Answer (score 1):

A code sample from Hipster.

```
import CoreMotion

let lengthFormatter = NSLengthFormatter()
let pedometer = CMPedometer()
pedometer.startPedometerUpdatesFromDate(NSDate(), withHandler: { data, error in
if !error {
    println("Steps Taken: \(data.numberOfSteps)")

    var distance = data.distance.doubleValue
    println("Distance: \(lengthFormatter.stringFromMeters(distance))")

    var time = data.endDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(data.startDate)
    var speed = distance / time
    println("Speed: \(lengthFormatter.stringFromMeters(speed)) / s")
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

After many hours playing around with the syntax, thinking I have made a rookie error, I tried alternative API's and found that the following works to grab pedometer data:

```
var ped2 = CMStepCounter()
    ped2.queryStepCountStartingFrom(dateMidnight, to: dateNow, toQueue: NSOperationQueue(), withHandler:{data, error in
        println("Test 2") // "Test 2"
        println(data) // 491 (I really should go for a walk!)
        println(error) // nil
        })
```

I will file a radar with Apple as it looks like a bug in the new API. Also the CMStepCounter class is due to be deprecated for CMPedometer. From CMStepCounter.h:

```
NS_CLASS_DEPRECATED_IOS(7_0,8_0,"Use CMPedometer instead")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're querying the data, which goes onto another thread. The execution continues after your call, and your NSNumber is still at 0. By the time you've come back you've printed the message a long time ago, and have no way of recovering the `stepsTaken`.

Comment: This might be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: @mhatch Hmm, I think I agree, but, now that I think about it, I've never seen guidance for which answer format to pick. A quick search didn't help. Do you happen to know where I might find it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a reference to your ped variable. Something like:

`self.ped = CMPedometer();`

Currently your ped variable is going out of scope before the handler is even called.